# Listing sources by combined percentage

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, numbers

> The production of wine will be *divided into* a 50% *given by* X and Y, a 20% *given by* W and V, and a 30% *given by* Z

Each percentage contains one or two kinds that make it up. I am unsure whether the usage of *divided into* and *given by* sounds weird or not. I am not even sure whether putting *a* before the percentage is fine. Bullet lists are not an option, but radically restructuring the sentence is fine.

Comment: You should avoid *divided into*, which is ordinarily a way of expressing the mathematical operation. Are you speaking here of the sources of the wine or its destinations?

Comment: What do the letters represent? Donors? Vineyards? Variables in mathematical formulas? Something else?

Comment: If you want to use the phrase "divided into", it would be more normal to say "will be divided into three parts, 50% ...". However, I don't understand what you mean by "given by X and Y", so there is still something odd about this sentence. Do you mean that the wine, once produced, will be divided? Or that the responsibility/expectation to produce wine is split among three groups, and their output will be combined?

Comment: I am trying to say that elements X and Y together will contribute for 50% to the total, W and V will contribute for 30%, etc... I concur it's very unclear what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If V, W, X, Y, and Z are *suppliers or types of input* (e.g., varieties of grapes):

- The wine will comprise 50% from X and Y;  20% from W and V, and 30% from Z.

If V, W, X, Y, and Z are *customers or destinations*:

- The wine will be {divided/distributed} among V, W, X, Y, and Z as follows: 50% to X and Y; 20% to W and V; 30% to Z.

None of these make sense to me; I would want to know what the individual percentages will be for each of the terms.  Because "50% {from/to} X and Y" could mean, say,  1% X and 49% Y, or 25% X and 25% Y, or 49% X and 1% Y.  Do you really mean to leave that much leeway/uncertainty?

Comment: They're types of input, more precisely different vine varieties. I don't have access to non-aggregated data so X and Y are summed together, I am afraid. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with: "The wine production will be composed of a 50% of X and Y, a 20% of W and V, and a 30% of Z"

Comment: Bad usage of "comprised".  Try "will comprise" or "will be composed of".  If you must, use the bastardized but common "comprised of". But definitely not "comprised by".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comprised+of%2C+comprises%2C+comprised+by&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccomprised%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcomprised%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BComprised%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomprises%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomprised%20by%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks @Brian Hitchcock, I edited my answer with your recomendations.